# HTML5 circle tag attributes with dynamic values angular5

Tags: html, angular5

In circle tag I have to pass **stroke-dashoffset** value  dynamically

```
<svg>
    <circle class="donut-segment" data-per="100" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="100 100" stroke-dashoffset="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

[image]

I am using angular5
How Can I pass it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<svg>
    <circle class="donut-segment" data-per="100" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="100 100" [stroke-dashoffset]="yourPropNameofComponent"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Not working Can't bind to 'stroke-dashoffset' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:circle'. (""15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="100 100" [ERROR ->][stroke-dashoffset]="percentage"></circle>

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution
**[attr.stroke-dashoffset]="percentage"** 
We can pass percentage value dynamically